# Have text displayed instead of numerical values on y axis

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Is it possible to display text instead of numerical values in the y axis of a line graph with Chart.JS?

Say that we have, for example, the following text-to-value `mapping`.

```
 0 = "sedentary"
 1 = "under-active"
 2 = "active" 
 ....
```

How can we display the words "sedentary", "under-active", etc instead of the numerical values in the following graph:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and you can achieve that using the **`userCallback`** function for y-axis ticks.

```js
var mapText = ['sedentary', 'under-active', 'active', 'inactive'];
var chart = new Chart(canvas, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Statistics',
         data: [3, 1, 2, 0],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.1)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.8)',
         borderWidth: 1,
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               maxTicksLimit: 4, //set as the 'mapText' array length
               stepSize: 1,
               userCallback: function(t, i) {
                  return mapText[mapText.length - (i + 1)];
               }
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```