# How to conditionally format text into tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my current graph made with matplotlib.  Is there a way to make the y-axis say "Down x%"

For instance instead of "-10%" I want it to say "Down 10%".  And the same for the rest of the ticks.

[image][image]

Something like this might be helpful if it were in python instead of JavaScript:  [Have text displayed instead of numerical values on y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935425/have-text-displayed-instead-of-numerical-values-on-y-axis)

Comment: Dupe of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51291089/7758804)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`FuncFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) to define any format you like for the ticks.

In this case, you could use a conditional statement to change the minus sign to `"Down"` only when the value is less than zero.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 5, 10]
y = [0, -25, -50]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y)

def myformat(x, pos):
    if x >= 0:
        return "{}%".format(x)
    else:
        return "Down {}%".format(-x)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(myformat))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]